# if product name in cart contains a string found in array woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to echo a string if a product in cart contains a word found in an array of strings, how to achive this in php woocommerce? I tried it using below code but did not work.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'review_order_before_submit_state_message' );
    function review_order_before_submit_state_message() {
          foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item){
    $product_name = $cart_item['data']->get_name() . '';
}

  $x = array('Fiat', 'Mercedez', '05150993');

  //If this is true, then
  if(in_array($product_name, $x, true)){
    echo '<span>Some Text</span>';
} 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it working using below code:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'review_order_before_submit_state_message' );
    function review_order_before_submit_state_message() {
          foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item){
    $product_name = $cart_item['data']->get_name();
}

  $x = array('fiat', 'mercedes-benz', '05150993');
 
 foreach ($x as $value) {
      if(str_contains(strtolower($product_name), $value, )){
    echo '<div>Some Text</div>';
} 
 }
 
    }
```